# how can I share my interactive map made in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I did an interactive using ggplot2 and ggplotly. How can I share it with another person?

Thanks,

Comment: pro tip: you can add the R tag

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ,first store it in an R variable, and install the htmlwidget package and use saveWidget() function to save your object to a file as below:

```
saveWidget(object_name, file="map.html")
```